# Adstock Power Lag transformation using for loops in r

Tags: r

The data set I am working on looks like this:

```
Var1 = c(3402,5206,4820,4608)
Var2 = c(0,122,126,0)
Data = cbind(Var1,var2)
```

Now I want to apply the Adstock, power and lag transformation respectively on the column variables which follows the logic:

```
Y1 = x1
Y2 = (x2+Y1*adstock)^power
Y3=(X3+y2*adstock)^power
…… so on
```

To achieve this I have used the following code—

```
    data=read.csv("APL_Test.csv",header=T)
    ind<-names(data)
    ind
    ad<-10
    pwr<-60
    lg<-1
    data[1] = data[1]
    for(i in 2:nrow(data))
{
     data[i] = data[i] + adstock_rate * data[i-1]
        ap = adstocked_advertising*power
        data[paste(ind,"_",ad,".",pwr,".",lg,sep="")]<-lag(ap,lg)
        data[,paste(ind,"_",ad,".",pwr,".",lg,sep="")]<- ifelse(is.na(data[,paste(ind,"_",ad,".",pwr,".",lg,sep="")]),data[,paste(ind,"_",ad,".",pwr,".",lg,sep="")][1],data[,paste(ind,"_",ad,".",pwr,".",lg,sep="")])
        }
```

---

In this regard I am facing the following issues:

1. The loop is not working properly for the multiple columns. However it’s working fine with the single column.
2. I want to automate the APL combinations where one would be able to get the transformation for multiple combinations using the loops.

Comment: The tag "apl" refers to the programming-language APL. Looking at your question, I wonder if that is what you wanted...? (Oh no, APL for "Adstock Power Lag" - I'll fix your tags...)

Comment: Could you take time to revise your question? R is case sensitive, and there is a lot of discrepancies.